# How do I migrate Play application from v2.2.5 to v2.3.5?

Tags: scala, playframework

It seems the new version of Play framework is using some new tool named "Activator" instead of the old "play" command line tool; what should I do to build my old project using this "Activator"? Any conversion steps?

Comment: You can go one level below and use `sbt` instead. That will work regardless of whether it was `play` or `activator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**activator** works as the **play** command. Just type `activator <command>`instead of `play <command>`.

There is a page in the Play documentation addressing your migration Problems:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.4/Migration23